# Why does setjmp traditionally save registers?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, setjmp

Just consider i386 as an example, but an analogous question applies to other archs. The traditional i386 `jmp_buf` saved by `setjmp` consists of 6 saved registers: `ebx`, `esi`, `edi`, `ebp`, `esp`, and `eip`. Of these, the first 4 are caller-saved per the ABI, so the function that called `setjmp` will itself overwrite them with its own saved values (which may change between the first and second return from `setjmp`). Thus, what is the point in saving these registers at all in the `jmp_buf`? Wouldn't it work just as well to save only the stack and instruction pointers?

**Edit:** I was mistakenly mixing up caller-saved and callee-saved, which was the entire source of the confusion. Apologies for wasting everybody's time.

Comment: What compiler and OS are we talking about?

Answer (score 5):

The setjmp/longjmp pair are not a "goto", they're a "save-state / restore-state" combo... this would not be possible if most of the registers were not saved; the exception being the subroutine return register, so you can identify if you returned from a normal call to setjmp, or via a longjmp.

Edit -- though the four you question are supposed to be caller saved, setjmp() isn't going to trust you... and it's going to do the right thing regardless of what you did ;)

Comment: But the values of caller-saved registers are not part of the state, at least not in any observable way I can identify. The restored values will be clobbered after `setjmp` returns but before they're ever read. This is what my question is about.

Comment: @R - you're looking at it as if the caller is written in C (or some other high level language that follows the same ABI)... but setjmp cannot afford to assume that. If the caller is written in assembly, all bets are off.

Comment: `setjmp` is part of the C language. If you're writing asm, that's outside the scope of C, but even then, if you're calling C functions, you have to assume the calling convention of the ABI you're working with, which governs how registers are handled.

Comment: If every function were written with the intention that it only be called from a specific environment, as your response suggests setjmp should have been, we would all be in trouble as software developers ;) It's one thing if you're developing for a closed environment (but even then it's ill-advised), but when developing a library others will call, either make it safe to be able to handle the unexpected, or expect it to eventually catch up to you in a bad way.

Comment: Every function built by the C compiler is built to assume it's called with the required calling convention. Your argument here is simply wrong; unfortunately also so was the premise of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "every function built by the C compiler"... setjmp() is written in assembly as a very platform-specific function (even when wrapped in a C function, it's still assembly that the C compiler passes right through), and callers can be built by non-C compilers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming `setjump` will overwrite those values (a fair assumption), however, I doubt that it could, because that would cause to make `longjmp` targets unstable, making it impossible to use.

lets say `ebx` had a pointer in it going into `setjmp`, when `longjmp` returns, that pointer *must* be restored, else we might get a nice exception, thus defeating the whole point of a non-local goto.

Taking a more practical look, we can see that the MS CRT doesn't tainted the registers before saving them:

```
MSVCR100._setjmp3 7>MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4]
73A030C4            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX],EBP
73A030C6            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+4],EBX
73A030C9            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+8],EDI
73A030CC            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+C],ESI
73A030CF            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+10],ESP
73A030D2            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
73A030D5            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+14],EAX
73A030D8            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+20],56433230
73A030DF            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+24],0
73A030E6            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0]
73A030EC            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+18],EAX
73A030EF            CMP EAX,-1
73A030F2            JNZ SHORT MSVCR100.73A030FD
73A030F4            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+1C],-1
73A030FB            JMP SHORT MSVCR100.73A03138
73A030FD            MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8]
73A03101            OR ECX,ECX                                                   ;  Switch (cases 0..8)
73A03103            JE SHORT MSVCR100.73A0310F
73A03105            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C]
73A03109            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+24],EAX
73A0310C            DEC ECX
73A0310D            JNZ SHORT MSVCR100.73A03117
73A0310F            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+C]                                 ;  Cases 0,1 of switch 73A03101
73A03112            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+1C],EAX
73A03115            JMP SHORT MSVCR100.73A03138
73A03117            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+10]
73A0311B            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+1C],EAX
73A0311E            DEC ECX
73A0311F            JE SHORT MSVCR100.73A03138
73A03121            PUSH ESI
73A03122            PUSH EDI
73A03123            LEA ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1C]
73A03127            LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+28]
73A0312A            CMP ECX,6
73A0312D            JBE SHORT MSVCR100.73A03134
73A0312F            MOV ECX,6                                                    ;  Default case of switch 73A03101
73A03134            REP MOVS DWORD PTR ES:[EDI],DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]               ;  Cases 3,4,5,6,7,8 of switch 73A03101
73A03136            POP EDI
73A03137            POP ESI
73A03138            SUB EAX,EAX                                                  ;  Case 2 of switch 73A03101
73A0313A            RETN
```

**Update**

there is a [standards document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setjmp.html) that states it must preserve the environment:

> A call to setjmp() shall save the calling environment in its env
>   argument for later use by longjmp().